# How to get imageView inside onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) in android

Tags: android, touch, imageview

I defined onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) to receive touch events for imageview. I am using multiple imageviews and i have to find for which imageview I have received touch event.
Is it possible to get imageview inside onTouchEvent?

```
public void createImageViews()
{
  int i = 0;

  imageArray[0] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
  imageArray[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
  imageArray[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
  imageArray[3] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4);
  imageArray[4] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image5);
  imageArray[5] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image6);

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    imageArray[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
  } 
}
 public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, AnimationListener { }
```

I have tried using

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { } but not receiving the touch events.
```

After starting the animation on imageview I did not observe touch events in onTouch() and getting touch events in onTouchEvent() .           imgArray[g_animCount].startAnimation(movArray[g_animCount]);

Comment: can you paste some code?

Comment: could you please tell me, what is imageArray here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use the below sample code snippet::::

    public class MyImageView extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_name);        
        int i = 0;
        imageArray[0] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imageArray[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
        imageArray[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
        imageArray[3] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4);
        imageArray[4] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image5);
        imageArray[5] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image6);

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)  {
            imageArray[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
         } 


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.image1:
        //your stuff
        break;
        case R.id.image2:
        //your stuff        
        break;
        case R.id.image3:
        //your stuff
        break;
        case R.id.image4:
         //your stuff
        break;
        case R.id.image5:
         //your stuff
        break;
        case R.id.image6:
         //your stuff
        break;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I am not receiving touch events inside @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { } so defined onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event). I have updated my imageview code in my question.

Comment: try it now must get tough events

Comment: After starting the animation on imageview I did not observe touch events in onTouch();    imgArray[g_animCount].startAnimation(movArray[g_animCount]);

Answer (score 3):

You can overide onTouchListener. The code for onTouchListener is

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
/// your stuff
}
```

use View v to know the touched view

Comment: I am not receiving touch events inside @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { } so defined onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event). I have updated my imageview code in my question.

Comment: @pavan why wouldn't you receive onTouch()? if you set your activity as the onTouchListener as I think you're doing  then you should be getting touch events...

Comment: I am not sure why touch events are not received in onTouch. I have my actvity like below, public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, AnimationListener { }

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:onClick="clickHandler"` for each `View` in your layout xml and define a method `public void clickHandler(View view)` in your `Activity` to handle the touch/click events.

This was introduced in 1.6.  Check this [LINK](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html) for more detail.

Comment: I have one more problem here, I can not find touch location. I mean x, y coordinates.

Comment: For one this only handles onClick - for another its not really good design to have the xml file be tied to the code file unless absolutely necessary - which nothing in his post suggests it should be

Comment: @pavan.  if you want x,y cords then you will need a touch listener.

Comment: @techiServices yes I have - I know it works, I'm just saying its not something you really want to do unless you're truly desperate to get a unique click event in a place where it would otherwise be very difficult or impossible, such as in a ListItem for a favorites star, etc.

Comment: @JRaymond.  so `For one this only handles onClick` is incorrect.  Also if you wanted to get a `unique click event...` you can just use `View.setOnClickListener` or `View.setOnTouchListener`.  Lastly if it is not a good idea why would google build the functionality?

Comment: @techiServices not intending to start a flamewar here, I'm just saying that in an ideal world, your XML layouts would have no tieback to the underlying code - theres just usually no reason for it to know, and it makes maintenance more difficult if you ever change function names to reuse the same layout.  It has its uses, which is why google put it in, but it isn't something to be used without knowing those tradeoffs. :)

Comment: After starting the animation on imageview I did not observe touch events in onTouch() and getting touch events in onTouchEvent() . imgArray[g_animCount].startAnimation(movArray[g_animCount]);